# Validation in flask

Tags: python, flask

I'am a noobie,I have checkboxes and a dropdown, I retrive the the values using request.form.getlist(" "). I want to proceed to further steps if value of dropdown is not present in value of checkboxes.

```
try:

    if drop not in check:
        return render_template('index.html')
except Exception:
    return render_template('error.html')
```

always it runs index.html even when drop value is present in check,
I'am not using wtforms.
How should I validate it? Thanks in advance

Comment: What are `drop` and `check` exactly? What sort of exception are you expecting it to raise to skip to the `except` block?

Comment: variables which contain the value of dropdown and checkbox, it just pops an alert if exception is raised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `drop` and `check` are the direct results of calling `flask.Request.form.getlist()`, then they're both lists. Your `if drop not in check` line is asking if the entire list `drop` is a member of the `check` list, which will never be the case. If there can only be one value for `drop`, use [`get`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get) instead of `getlist` to get a single value. Otherwise, check the list you're grabbing and pick one value from it to test against `check`.

This all assumes that `drop` and `check` look like what you expect them to look like. If just using a single value of `drop` doesn't work like you expect, put something in to display the values of `drop` and `check` so you can see what they actually look like.

Comment: I added else in try block it worked but it does not work with exception.

Comment: @rey I don't understand what you mean by "it does not work with exception".

Comment: instead of except block I added else in try block which returns error.html it worked, but when I remove else and add except block it returns view function did not return a response.

Comment: @rey That's because if `drop` is a member of `check`, then the first `return` is skipped. Then, since no exception is raised, the second `return` in the `except` block is also skipped. You'll either need an `else` block, or something happening *after* the `except` block.

Comment: thanks I got it, previously I tried both the values with get instead of get list it did't work so I had to post the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [wtforms](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with validation like:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
```

Class of Form will check validation.

Comment: `form.validate_on_submit()` covers both method==POST and validate

Comment: @ThiefMaster. Sorry, I didn't know it. Thanks for new information to me.